# SQL to get total outstanding balance meeting withdrawal criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a payments table that has a user_id and an amount. Users have a minimum withdrawal of $5.00, and they can have any number of payments to them. Their total balance isn't stored anywhere (to keep it simple and avoid synchronization issues), instead it's found by doing a query like:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
  FROM payment 
 WHERE user_id = 5;
```

I want to find out the grand total of all balances that meet the withdrawal requirement. What I wish I could do is something like:

```
  SELECT SUM(SUM(amount)) 
    FROM payment 
   WHERE sum(amount) >= 5.00
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Unfortunately I get the error

> ERROR:  aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause

How can I write this query? I'm using postgres 8.4.

#### Part 2:

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but this payments table also includes payments made *by* the user: the payment table includes amount, from_user_id, and to_user_id. It's a single-entry accounting system. It would be great if I could also subtract the payments the user has made. The pseudo-sql is:

```
SELECT (sum of all amounts) 
 WHERE (sum(amount where to_user_id = 5) - sum(amount where from_user_id = 5)) > 5.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [HAVING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP)

Never heard anyone try and do nested aggregation. I suggest you do the inner bit separately, either with a `with` statment or using something like

```
select sum(foo) from (select sum(amount) as foo ...having ...)
```

I believe you want something like this for your second part, though I might be second-guessing.

```
with a as(
  select sum(amount) as credit, from_user from payment group by from_user
), b as (
  select sum(amount) as debit, to_user from payment group by to_user
)
-- glossing over any null values with coalesce:
select to_user, coalesce(credit,0) - coalesce(debit,0) -- coalesce users perhaps?
from a outer join b on from_user = to_user
where coalesce(credit,0) - coalesce(debit,0) > limit -- or vice-versa
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me part of it. I still can't sum(sum(amount)) - it says you can't nest aggregation. Is there a way to do that part?

Comment: I've never heard anyone try and do nested aggregation. I suggest you do the inner bit separately, either with a `with` statment or with something like `select sum(foo) from (select sum(amount) as foo ...having ...)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Any idea how to do part 2? I have no idea how to keep the two sum(amount)'s separate (one sum for to_user minus sum for from_user)

Comment: Thanks, it works - one correction: it has to be an outer join, otherwise users who never sent money wouldn't have a balance, but otherwise it's great.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the HAVING clause.

The following will give you all the users who have a balance greater than 5.00.  You could then loop through in your programming language to get the total balance.
`SELECT sum(amount) FROM payment GROUP BY user_id HAVING sum(amount) >= 5.00 ;`

I can't think of a way to get it all into one efficient SQL statement, but I'll keep thinking.

I don't think I have an answer to your part 2 either, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

#### Part 1: Aggregates, and the `HAVING` clause

In SQL, the `WHERE` clause does not support using an aggregate (IE: MIN, MAX, SUM, COUNT, etc) that is not within a subquery or derived table/inline view.  Such cases can only be handled in the `HAVING` clause:

```
  SELECT SUM(p.amount) 
    FROM PAYMENT p
GROUP BY p.to_user_id
  HAVING SUM(p.amount) >= 5.00
```

#### Part 2:

Because a user could have only payments to their account, or the opposite - you need to get a list of users to outer join to:

```
   SELECT COALESCE(x.debit, 0) - COALESCE(y.credit, 0) AS balance
     FROM (SELECT a.from_user_id AS user
             FROM PAYMENT a
           UNION 
           SELECT b.to_user_id
             FROM PAYMENT b) z
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.to_user_id,
                  SUM(t.payment) AS debit
             FROM PAYMENT t
         GROUP BY t.to_user_id) x ON x.to_user_id = z.user
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.from_user_id,
                  SUM(t.payment) AS credit
             FROM PAYMENT t
         GROUP BY t.from_user_id) y ON y.from_user_id = z.user
    WHERE COALESCE(x.debit, 0) - COALESCE(y.credit, 0) >= 5.00
 GROUP BY z.user
```